# Compute $P(\{6|xy\})$ and $P(\{8|xy\})$ if $x$ and $y$ are independent random positive integers (Please edit this post if it is ill-formed)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If $x$ and $y$ are independent random positive integers,
 1. How to compute the probability of $(2*3)|xy$ ?
 2. How to compute the probability of $(2^3)|xy$ ?

Comment: Computation of the probabilities requires knowledge of joint distribution of $x$ and $y$. Further the notation $P(6\mid xy)$ is a bit tricky because $|$ is also used by the notation of conditional probabilities. Personally I would choose for $P(\{6\mid xy\})$ to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: That, or $P(6\ \text{divides}\ xy)$.

Comment: Even assuming that $x$ and $y$ are independent (as you do) and that they are identically distributed (as you fail to do but probably mean to do), there is no canonical uniform distribution on the set of integers hence one really ought to specify the distribution considered before answering the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For both problems it is necessary to set up a probabilistic environment.

The divisibility of $xy$ by $6$ depends only on the remainders of $x$ and $y$ modulo $6$. It is natural to assume that both $x$ and $y$ are independently and uniformly distributed modulo $6$. In this case they are as well independently and uniformly distributed modulo $2$ and $3$. The probability that $x$ is not divisible by $2$ is ${1\over2}$. Therefore with probability $1-{1\over2}\cdot{1\over2}={3\over4}$ at least one of $x$ or $y$ is divisible by $2$. Similarly, the probability that $x$ is not divisible by $3$ is ${2\over3}$.
Therefore with probability $1-{2\over3}\cdot{2\over3}={5\over9}$ at least one of $x$ or $y$ is divisible by $3$. It follows that with probability $p={3\over4}\cdot{5\over9}={15\over36}$ the product $xy$ is divisible by $6$.

The divisibility of $xy$ by $8$ depends only on the remainders of $x$ and $y$ modulo $8$. It is natural to assume that both $x$ and $y$ are independently and uniformly distributed modulo $8$. The following cases lead to divisibility of $xy$ by $8$:
$$\eqalign{x\in\{1,3,5,7\}\quad&\wedge\quad y=0,\cr
x\in\{2,6\}\quad&\wedge\quad y\in\{0,4\},\cr
x=4\quad&\wedge\quad y\in\{0,2,4,6\},\cr
x=0\quad&\wedge\quad y\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}\ .\cr}$$
Therefore the probability that $xy$ is divisible by $8$ is given by
$$q={1\over2}\cdot{1\over8}+{1\over4}\cdot{1\over4}+{1\over8}\cdot{1\over2}+{1\over8}\cdot1={5\over16}\ .$$

Answer (score -1):

Things might get more easy to compute by realizing that:$$\{6\mid xy\}=\{6\mid x\}\cup\{6\mid y\}\cup(\{2\mid x\}\cap\{3\mid y\})\cup(\{3\mid x\}\cap\{2\mid y\})$$
combined with the application of the principle of inclusion/exclusion.

This approach might be fruitful especially if $x$ and $y$ are independent.

Success not guaranteed, though.

Comment: My imature intuition is that $P(\{6|xy\})=1/6$, is it true ?

Comment: As said in my comment on your question: this requires knowledge of the joint distribution of $x$ and $y$. If that lacks then nothing can be said about that, and there is no reason to think that it equals $\frac16$. If e.g. $P(x=1=y)=1$ then the probability equals $0$.

Comment: Oops, thank you! I should study more thoroughly! :-)

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: For the 2nd problem, do it in this way $\{8|xy\}=\{8|x\}\cup\{8|y\}\cup(\{4|x\}\cap\{2|y\})\cup(\{2|x\}\cap\{4|y\})$ right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.